# list.files error (easy?) [R]

Tags: r, list

Im trying to r.bind all files in certain directory with the following code in R (all files are formatted the same way):

```
gene_list <- list.files("/nethome/genelist/")   
gene_CH <- do.call("rbind",lapply(gene_list, FUN=function(files)
         {read.table(files,   header=TRUE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)}))
write.table(gene_CH,"/nethome/genelist/all.genes.CH_v2t.txt",sep="\t",quote=F,row.names=F)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'A2ML1_v2t.txt': No such file or directory
```

Thing is, A2ML1_v2t.txt is in the directory. Also, what is more puzzling (to me anyway) is that this code worked this morning.  But for some reason, its not working now.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. This morning, your working directory was /nethome/genelist/, but now, it isn't. `list.files()` only gives filenames, not absolute paths, so your second line will search through the current working directory. Try `getwd()` to check and `setwd()` to change it.
2. You do have read permission in the directory, do you?

Comment: My money's on 1. If so, try the `full.names` argument to `list.files`, which is probably a good idea anyway.

Comment: Yep - I think it was because I wasn't in the correct directory - changing that worked.  Using `full.names = T` allows me to be in another directory while letting me run the code.